# Strip out epoch date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I am having a datatable return a number of Dates received - they are coming back in the format below(will always take this format):

```
/Date(1362045881257)/
```

how can I easily strip this to just the epoch digits so I can then convert into a readable date.

I have tried the following so far but it is not working as expected.  So the first thing I was trying to remove was just the ( ) - then I was going to do another .replace to remove the / / and then remove the Date which would leave me with just the digits.

```
            success: function (msg) {

                for (var i = 0; i < msg.aaData.length; i++) {

                    var date = msg.aaData[i].DateReceived;
                    date.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
                    alert(date);
                }

                fnCallback(msg);
            },
```

Comment: `replace`returns the result, but does not do the changes on the string itself. so you need to do `date = date.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');`

Comment: A yes - silly mistake - just needed a fresh set of eyes - cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
        success: function (msg) {

            for (var i = 0; i < msg.aaData.length; i++) {
                // toString() below might be redundant!
                var date = msg.aaData[i].DateReceived.toString();
                var reg = /[^0-9]/g;
                var epoch = date.replace(reg, ''));
                alert(epoch);
            }

            fnCallback(msg);
        },
```